# Determining which non-G+ users are coming to my event

Tags: google-plus-events

I've created an event and invited non-G+ users to it.

They are able to respond, but when they do all G+ shows me is:

[image: screenshot showing the text "2 people not using Google+"]

Not terribly useful! Is there any way to figure out who these people are? Clicking on the "2 people not using Google+" doesn't do anything.